# How to play an audio file when microphone input exceeds some threshold in dm

Tags: audio, playback, microphone

Is there any program, or any console-script, that listens to microphone input and when noise exceeds some threshold in db, plays back an audio file?

Answer (score 0):

One thing to muse on is that when recording with sox (using rec for example) sox outputs a text signal meter which produces a number of '=' characters depending on input level and an exclamation point character when it detects clipping, plus a count of samples clipped. If you can stream this output to a detector script looking for the count of '=' or ! character or changes to the count of clipped samples then the same script could trigger audio output as desired.